# If you integrate a continuous function, is the result always continuous also?

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

I have been looking through an example problem with a lecturer. I need to show that a continuous function once integrated, is also continuous. They explained that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells you this is the case. Having looked at the Theorem though, I'm not entirely sure what part tells me that this is the case. I'm not looking for a proof, merely a statement that says that my query is true. Could anyone help me see where this is mentioned in the Theorem? All help appreciated

Comment: The theorem says that if $f$ is continuous, then the function $x \mapsto \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is differentiable. Don't you see the link with the continuity of this function ?

Comment: The antiderivative of *any* integrable function is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the FTC statement from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements):

> Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$. Let $F$ be the function defined, for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, by
> $$
> F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\, \mathrm{d}t
> $$
> Then $F$ is ***uniformly continuous*** on $[a,b] \dots$

Since $F$ is defined to be the continuous function $f$ being integrated, and since [uniform continuity $\implies$ continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1103135/695196), you can conclude that $F$ is also continuous on $[a,b]$.